# Jump to ID after ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following form. After the search form is submitted and results are returned via an ajax call, I would like the page to jump to an ID - which happens to be the top of the results.

```
<form class="avail-form">
  ...
   <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>

<div id="results">Results Found</div>
.
. Results
.
```

Current attempt that doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.avail-form').click(function() {
        $(this).scrollTop($('#results').offset().top);
    });
});
```

I tried using `submit` instead of `click` with no luck. I tried a bunch of different apporaches but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Are you aware that your javascript is missing a closing single quote in the selector?

Comment: @musefan - you mean a single quote, right ?

Comment: sorry, typo on my end. it wasn't a direct copy and paste, but currently matches what I have in my code.

Comment: so next problem. Where is your AJAX call? You need to call your `scrollTop` code when the AJAX completes

Comment: You're sure you should'nt be scrolling the window, the body or even the document, and not the form ?

Comment: @adeneo you are right. I should be scrolling the window.

Comment: @adeneo is correct...the $(this) variable is telling the form to scroll, not the body or document..so nothing's happening. Did you try changing the $(this) to document instead?

Comment: yes, see Palash's suggestion below and the result I got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the hash when the request completes.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function(){
        window.location.hash = "#results";
    }
});
```